# Is there any limit on the number of aggregate Functions on different columns in a query?

Tags: oracle

Is there any limit on the number of aggregate Functions on different columns in a query?
example

```
SELECT SUM(col1), AVG(col2), SUM(col3), ... FROM table;
```

DB- Oracle

and if yes, why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's none, as far as I can tell. Why do you think there is, or that there should be?

Oracle limits e.g. number of columns in a table to 1000 (as of 19c version), but - this is a `SELECT` column list, no matter you use aggregates on different columns.

I did a test (and so can you) on Scott's sample schema:

```
create table test (col clob);

declare
  l_str varchar2(32000) := 'select ';
  l_col varchar2(20);
begin
  for i in 1 .. 1010 loop
    l_col := case when substr(i, -1) = 1 then 'sum(sal)'
                  when substr(i, -1) = 3 then 'avg(empno)'
                  when substr(i, -1) = 5 then 'max(job)'
                  else 'min(deptno)'
             end;
    l_str := l_str || l_col ||',';
  end loop;
  
  l_str := rtrim(l_str, ',') || ' from emp';
  insert into test values (l_str);
end;
/  

select * From test;
```

Result is such a looooong string (1010 columns in total):

```
select sum(sal),min(deptno),avg(empno),min(deptno),max(job), ... from emp
```

which returns a result. For demonstration purposes, I shortened the query as it won't work in SQL*Plus because of "SP2-0027: Input is too long (> 2499 characters) - line ignored". It runs OK with 1010 columns in e.g. TOAD:

```
SQL> select sum(sal),min(deptno),avg(empno),min(deptno),max(job),min(deptno) from emp;

  SUM(SAL) MIN(DEPTNO) AVG(EMPNO) MIN(DEPTNO) MAX(JOB)  MIN(DEPTNO)
---------- ----------- ---------- ----------- --------- -----------
     29025          10 7726,57143          10 SALESMAN           10

SQL>
```

So, no problem.

Comment: The reason I thought if there is a limit is performance, Query will be terribly slow if it is forced to use disk memory because of overflow in the aggregate area in the memory. Well, that makes clear there is no limit.

Comment: Well, I don't know anyone who would write such a query *manually*. I used a *generator* to do that for testing purposes. Besides, what would be a practical use of such a query? Usually, if your procedure doesn't fit an A4 (or Letter) paper format, it is already too long :) The same goes with a query result - who can review 100 columns and make some conclusion out of it? Heck, 20 columns are too much for me. I'd shoot myself if I had to review 1000 columns :)

Comment: Yup practically no one does that that's why I was curious if there is a situation where lots of aggregate functions are used then there is a limit or not.